# MongoDB available "disk" space (outside DB)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

As part of a maintenance check/function I'm building for a Windows service using a MongoDB on a Linux server I need to show how much disk/drive space is available for the Database(s) to grow into.

Is this at all possible using the MongoDB engine itself? I'm trying to avoid writing a different component that will SSH into the server independently.

The idea behind this is to report when the percentage space available drops below a specific threshold by sending a notification email to configured users.

PS. The services are written in C#, but that should make no difference to the solution.

Comment: have you tried db.stats? have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147739/mongodb-avoid-excessive-disk-space

Comment: Yes, stats only shows you what's inside the database. I'm interested on what's available on the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try using MongoDB MMS https://mms.mongodb.com/ and then add in hardware monitoring via the munin plugin:

https://mms.mongodb.com/help/tutorial/configure-monitoring/

MMS is a great tool for overall MongoDB monitoring by itself, is free plus also has these additional hardware monitoring capabilities for Linux installations.

Comment: According to the descriptions MMS is "cloud based". Does that mean the service will have to be permanently connected to the internet? The data that we work with is quite sensitive and we call allow any data, or performance for that matter, outside the local network.

Comment: The friendly people at MongoDB cleared this up for me. With our license we can install an OnPremise version that will run without an internet connection. 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CS-12619
I will then also need to install the munin plugin as you suggested. They have created a feature request ticket to include this functionality in a future release of MMS.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MMS-569

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible with MongoDB itself. You have to use MMS in conjunction with munin as described in answer above.